# Underscore to camelCase, exclude leading underscore

Tags: php, regex

I’d like to transform lower_underscore to lowerCamelCase however preserving leading underscores in PHP.

Examples:

```
foo_bar -> fooBar
foo -> foo
_foo_bar -> _fooBar
_foo -> _foo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my final solution:

```
preg_replace_callback('/(?!^)_([a-z])/', function($string)
{
    return strtoupper($string[1]);
}, $string);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
[a-zA-Z](_[a-zA-Z])
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tT5fK5/1)